# Files appearing in "unstaged files", but can't stage (red blocking icon)

Tags: eclipse, git, gitkraken

I have files that have no changes, but appear to be stuck in the staging area.

I started a bitbucket repo from an existing project and from the command line did a  `$ git remote add origin https://myusername@bitbucket.org/username/myrepo.git` in my local project folder. Then did and initial commit from the command line as well `$ git push -u origin master`. I then loaded the project into the [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/) IDE using the IDE command `File>Import Project From File System`. After doing this, I found that some of the files from my project where in the staging area, but did not have any changes done to them and clicking them in gitkraken also reported that they were unchanged (yet I could not find a way to remove them from the unstaged files area). Trying to stage these files makes the clicking hand icon flash as a red blocking symbol and nothing else happens.

I tried staging and pushing these "ghost changes" manually in the cli, and get this output:

```
➜  myproject git:(master) git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .classpath
        modified:   .project
        modified:   some-query.sql

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  myproject git:(master) git add .classpath .project some-query.sql
➜  myproject git:(master) git commit .classpath .project some-query.sql
...
<some git commit text>
...
➜  myproject git:(master) git push -u origin master
Password for 'https://myusername@bitbucket.org':
....
<some git push success text>
....
```

However, these files still appear in the "unstaged files" area.

If anyone has any idea what is going on here, input would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I see a `git add` but no `git commit`.

Comment: Updates question to show that committing does not solve the problem of the files still being *stuck* in the gitkraken UI "unstaged files" area.

Comment: So I have the same problem. In my case it is the sub-git "Pod", and so I open that to do a commit on it, and now I get a specific error, that one file in my SciChart module "SciPieSeriesDataView.nib" is a directory. Which it is not. Trying to resolve it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to commit the files.

```
git commit -m "adding .classpath, .project, and some-query.sql modifications"
```

Look up info on the difference between the working directory, the index, and the repo (there is a fourth area, called the stash, as well).  When you stage you are just moving files and changes from the working directory into the index.  To actually put those changes into your repo, you need to commit them, which will only commit the things in the index, not the changes just in the working directory.

So initially, the changes were just in your working directory.  After `git add <files>`, they were staged in the index, but not committed.  After `git commit` or `git commit -m "<message>"` then they are moved into a new commit in your local repo.  It is only at this point that push will do anything, because push only moves commits (and references) from local to remote repos, it doesn't touch the working directory or index.

Comment: Thanks for that reminder. In any case, even after committing there are still the files in the "unstaged files" area of the gitkraken UI that don't go away and show that the file has 'no changes'. Updated question to reflect changes.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Interesting - so there is something that Git is viewing as different in the files in it's compare routines, but once it gets translated into the diff output, those changes are no longer present.  Could it be a Unix vs. Windows end-line or something like that?  Can you store the file from a prior commit, checkout the current commit, and then do a diff directly on the 2 files?  You may want to modify the end-line behavior (i.e. set the flag to always checkout with unix, and commit with unix end-lines), recommit 1 or 2 times and see if it goes away.

Comment: More or less - need to figure out what Git thinks is different in the repo compare to after it is extracted into the working directory.